# JavaScript adding multiple values in an array on a single click

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my HTML Code:

```
<table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-bordered" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
```

This is i have done a JSON dump in table:

```
$("#datatable-buttons").DataTable({
                                              dom: "Bfrtip",
                                              buttons: [
                                                  {
                                                      extend: "copy",
                                                      className: "btn-sm"
                                                  },
                                                  {
                                                      extend: "csv",
                                                      className: "btn-sm"
                                                  },
                                                  {
                                                      extend: "excel",
                                                      className: "btn-sm"
                                                  },
                                                  {
                                                      extend: "pdfHtml5",
                                                      className: "btn-sm"
                                                  },
                                                  {
                                                      extend: "print",
                                                      className: "btn-sm"
                                                  },
                                              ],
                                              "aaData": [
                                                  {
                                                      "Name": "Tiger Nixon",
                                                      "Position": "System Architect",
                                                      "Office": "$320,800",
                                                      "Age": "2011/04/25",
                                                      "Start date": "Edinburgh",
                                                      "Salary": "5421"
                                                  },
                                                  {
                                                      "Name": "Garrett Winters",
                                                      "Position": "Accountant",
                                                      "Office": "$170,750",
                                                      "Age": "2011/07/25",
                                                      "Start date": "Tokyo",
                                                      "Salary": "8422"
                                                  },
                                                  {
                                                      "Name": "Ashton Cox",
                                                      "Position": "Junior Technical Author",
                                                      "Office": "$86,000",
                                                      "Age": "2009/01/12",
                                                      "Start date": "San Francisco",
                                                      "Salary": "1562"
                                                  },
                                                  {
                                                      "Name": "Cedric Kelly",
                                                      "Position": "Senior Javascript Developer",
                                                      "Office": "$433,060",
                                                      "Age": "2012/03/29",
                                                      "Start date": "Edinburgh",
                                                      "Salary": "6224"
                                                  }
                                              ],
                                              "aoColumns": [
                                                  { "mData": "Name" },
                                                  { "mData": "Position" },
                                                  { "mData": "Office" },
                                                  { "mData": "Age" },
                                                  { "mData": "Start date" },
                                                  { "mData": "Salary" }
                                              ],
                                              responsive: true
                                            });
        }
```

This is MY JQuery Code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#datatable-buttons tbody tr', function()
        {
            if ($(this).hasClass('bg-info'))
                {
                  counter--;
                  if(counter == 0)
                    {
                        $("#actions").html("");
                    }
                  else if(counter == 1)
                    {
                        var val1 = $(this).closest("tr").children(":first").text();
                        var idx = $.inArray(val1, dataId);
                        if (idx == -1)
                            {
                                dataId.push(val1);
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                dataId.splice(idx, 1);
                            }
                        console.log(dataId);
                        $("#actions").html("<button class='btn btn-primary'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></i></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class='btn btn-warning'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></i></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class='btn btn-danger'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i></button>");
                    }
                  else if(counter > 1)
                    {
                        var val1 = $(this).closest("tr").children(":first").text();
                        var idx = $.inArray(val1, dataId);
                        if (idx == -1)
                            {
                                dataId.push(val1);
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                dataId.splice(idx, 1);
                            }
                        console.log(dataId);
                        $("#actions").html("<button class='btn btn-danger'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i></button>");
                    }

                  $(this).removeClass('bg-info');
                }
            else
                {
                  counter++;
                  if(counter == 0)
                    {
                        $("#actions").html("");
                    }
                  else if(counter == 1)
                    {
                        var val1 = $(this).closest("tr").children(":first").text();
                        var idx = $.inArray(val1, dataId);
                        if (idx == -1)
                            {
                                dataId.push(val1);
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                dataId.splice(idx, 1);
                            }
                        console.log(dataId);                            
                        $("#actions").html("<button class='btn btn-primary'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></i></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class='btn btn-warning'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></i></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class='btn btn-danger'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i></button>");
                    }
                  else if(counter > 1)
                    {
                        var val1 = $(this).closest("tr").children(":first").text();
                        var idx = $.inArray(val1, dataId);
                        if (idx == -1)
                            {
                                dataId.push(val1);
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                dataId.splice(idx, 1);
                            }
                        console.log(dataId);
                        $("#actions").html("<button class='btn btn-danger'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i></button>");
                    }
                  else
                    {
                        // 
                    }
                    $(this).addClass('bg-info');
                    console.log(dataId);
                } 
        });

        // $(document).on('click', '#datatable-buttons tbody tr td i.glyphicon.glyphicon-edit.edit', function()
        //  {
        //      var specificValue = $(this).closest("tr").children(":first").text();
        //      alert("Edit Clicked For " + specificValue);
        //  });

        // $(document).on('click', '#datatable-buttons tbody tr td i.glyphicon.glyphicon-trash.delete', function()
        //  {
        //    $(this).closest("tr").remove().slideUp("slow");
        //  });
```

What i want to acheieve is i have created an array `dataId` in which i want to push the values of the current row that is clicked then after again a row is clicked i want to check whether the values exists or not if the value exists then remove that element from array and if not present then add it.

Currently i have implemented a code but it add the values 2 times whenever i click on a row.

What might be the code problem. Any helps appreciated. _/_

Comment: Create a working demo that reproduces problem. Note that most of the duplicated code can easily be reduced

Comment: var dataId=[] ?

Comment: What is the meaning of the global counter? NB: you have a lot of duplication of code.

Comment: are you sure you are getting right value in val1 ?